# Change internet link when fault

Tags: linux, internet, traffic, high-availability

Situation:

- 2 internet links - A and B - both connected to linux router.
- 2 routing tables, one with default via A, second default via B.
- iptables and ip rule select "best" table for specific traffic.

Everything works ok, but - it's static configuration.

What do - if one of internet links fail? In this scenario everything should go via second, proper link. And - when failed link is up - everything should back to situation where traffic go via both links.

Are there any "standard" tools to do such things? this is not problem to write something(script) what do such things - but - maybe there are more standard tools?

(definition of failed link - one of important ip is inaccessible from specific link, but it's accessible from second link).

Comment: Does the link actually go down (i.e. the interface itself does down, such as if it's a `ppp` link) or is there a separate router that hides that from you? In the latter case you will need some way to determine if a link is down and act accordingly.

Comment: ok - i precised question. there are routers of isps - so - link isn't down. Currently - there is test using wget/ping via both links to specific site, and if one of them fail - this link os marked as down

Answer (score 2):

My multi-WAN Draytek routers can use either ping or arp to monitor keep-alive across ethernet and VPN links. (Obviously for xDSL there are better alternatives.) Ssh and OpenVPN can be configured to generate internal keepalives. I don't know of any other standard approach.

Something like this (untested):

```
ROUTE1=up LINK1=up COUNT1=3
ROUTE2=up LINK2=up COUNT2=3
SHOUT=once

while sleep 5
do
    if ping {destination_via1}
    then
        LINK1_UP=up COUNT1=3
    else
        [[ 0 -lt $COUNT1 ]] && COUNT1=$((COUNT1 - 1))
        [[ 0 -ge $COUNT1 ]] && LINK1=down
    fi

    if ping {destination_via2}
    then
        LINK2_UP=up COUNT2=3
    else
        [[ 0 -lt $COUNT2 ]] && COUNT2=$((COUNT2 - 1))
        [[ 0 -ge $COUNT2 ]] && LINK2=down
    fi


    if [[ down = $LINK1 -a up = $ROUTE1 ]]
    then
        # add code here to remove route via LINK1 #
        ROUTE1=down
    elif [[ up = $LINK1 -a down = $ROUTE1 ]]
        # add code here to add route via LINK1 #
        ROUTE1=up
        SHOUT=once
    fi

    if [[ down = $LINK2 -a up = $ROUTE2 ]]
    then
        # add code here to remove route via LINK2 #
        ROUTE2=down
    elif [[ up = $LINK2 -a down = $ROUTE2 ]]
        # add code here to add route via LINK2 #
        ROUTE2=up
        SHOUT=once
    fi

    if [[ once = $SHOUT -a down = $ROUTE1 -a down = $ROUTE2 ]]
    then
        # add code here to shout that both routes are down #
        SHOUT=no
    fi
done
```

Comment: i have currently something like it. but - i seek for more advenced solution, not based on own simple script ;) and - works more live, not every few seconds.

Comment: @undefine, given that TCP timeouts are in the order of tens of seconds I'm not sure how you could measure a link dying in much less that 10-20 second intervals. This approach I've offered uses a "3 tries and you're out" scheme just in case there is a transient failure during the ping test. If you allow 1 second for the ping test itself (`ping -c1 -w1 www.example.net`) then you have a potential 3*(5+1), i.e 18 seconds before the link gets dropped.